# Having Latest Versions of all Apps in Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: linux, ubuntu, arch-linux, apt

As we all know that Arch Linux repository is updated with all the latest releases of all the softwares. But in Ubuntu, The repo is not updated that often resulting in user using the older versions of the softwares. I need a workaround,Tip or repo for Ubuntu 12.10 such that I should be able to get all the latest versions of the apps released.

Comment: I guess the only way which works for *all* given applications is to compile it from the original source code and then create a `DEB` package. Are you sure you need the newest version of *all* applications? If you do, then Ubuntu is probably not the right distribution for you.

Comment: @Marco I am 100% sure to get the late versions for all apps.

Comment: I don't understand the comment. If you get the latest versions, where is the problem? All distributions that package software is some way introduce a delay, which means that you will never be able to get the newest versions *at any time*, only after some delay. The only way out is to directly use the developers source repos. But throwing together the most recent commits of all pieces of software (even if you just consider the stable branches) the result would be fairly unstable and not usable for daily production or reliable serious work. You should reconsider your approach IMO.

Comment: @Marco I am not getting the latest versions now, I need a repo for Ubuntu which might provide me with latest releases without much delay as Arch Linux does

Comment: For a small amount of applications you can try to find `PPA`s for those applications. Otherwise there's probably no other option than to do compile the apps yourself.

Comment: I suggest you to read about rolling vs non-rolling releasing in software development. Explained for example [here: Wikipedia - Rolling Release](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_release). Non receiving newer versions doesn't mean it's unmaintained or not receiving bugfixes (possibly backported).

Comment: Updating all software to the latest release would mean that it is by definition no longer Ubuntu 12.10.

Answer (score 3):

It is by design - Ubuntu is basically Debian unstable. If you need the cutting (and bleeding) edge you may want to try Debian experimental or a rolling release distro like Slackware, openSUSE Tumbleweed, Arch Linux... or just go for Gentoo.

Comment: +1 Gentoo's Portage works great for controlling the degree of cut/bleed, be it per package or for the whole system. The same probably goes for the rest of the distro's mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Here is How you can solve this issue :

Apt (advanced-packaging-tool) is an excellent tool to install/remove programs and packages on linux. The problem is that programs and packages sometimes are too old.

To help solve this problems you can use an external repository using ppa (personal package archive) to get more recent versions of your software/packages.

Let's take nginx for example. The version on apt is 1.1.19 (at the time I wrote this), but you can find the newest version using the nginx/stable ppa repository which is 1.2.6.

Let's see how it works:

add-apt-repository ppa:nginx/stable

```
add-apt-repository ppa: < user > / < package >
```

Update your apt packages

```
apt-get update
```

Install nginx

```
apt-get install nginx
```

Find more repositories for your linux distro on: https://launchpad.net/